# Kafka state store as local persistence option?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple distributed systems architecture with one producer system which writes events to one kafka topic. These events are basically consumed by only one system. This consumer loads all events into memory, which has to happen on every consumer restart.

There's a challenge because there are a lot of events in this topic, and they have a very high retention time. Because of this, the consumer has to replay a lot of events on every restart, which takes a long time.

To mitigate this, I'd like to introduce some kind of local persistence (projection) on consumer side, to which the consumer writes on event processing from the topic and from which the current event state up until the latest persisted offset can be read on startup, before newer events are again consumed from the topic directly.
Is this what the kafka persistent state store can do, out of the box?
So far I've read only about stateful streaming applications which use the state store for e.g. aggregation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Storage is still a form of aggregation. You're not required to reduce the data, such as sums or averages on numbers.

Yes, [state stores](https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores) offer the features you're looking for, and Kafka Streams should expose a health check for catching up from the store before resuming consumption.